# ng test wont recognize angular material components

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im tryng to test my application with NG TEST but the i use angular material in one of my components and they are not recognized as known elements in angular. How can i fix this?

the errors are like this :

```
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<form class="example-form">
    [ERROR ->]<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Usuário" [formControl"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/TableComponent.html@2:4
Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'.
1. If 'mat-table' is an Angular component and it has 'dataSource' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Three things you should check:

1. if you already have imported **`MatFormFieldModule`** in you `app.module`
2. if it has been added to **`imports`** array in **`@NgModule`**, and also in `TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})` because it's about test files `xxx.component.spec.ts`: 
   `imports:[MatFormFieldModule,...]`
3. if you have imported **`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`**:

   `import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';` in `app.module.ts` and `xxxx.component.spec.ts`, and if it has been added to **`@NgModule`** and **`TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})`** `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`.

For the last/third one, the error message is quite clear:

`To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("</form>.....`

Comment: Thanks! This, along with the suggestion of importing `MaterialModule` to `TestBed.configureTestingModule` from this [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2478#issuecomment-306613282) fixed all the errors I had while running `ng test`.

Comment: Glad it did help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material Components can be used after importing the Module for the component in app.module.ts. You can check the module to be imported in API Tab on official documentation - https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api.

The error will fixed for mat-form-field after importing the following module but you will also need to import the other modules.

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```